# Interpreting String as function name - ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a game for a university assignment and I want to create a class that handles all the assets from the fla file's library. I've been developing websites with OO PHP for almost 4 years so I have programming experience, but I'm new to AS3.

The Asset handler class:

```
package library {
    public class AssetHandler {
        public var stageWidth: int;
        public var stageHeight: int;

        public function AssetHandler(sw:int, sh:int):void {
            stageWidth = sw;
            stageHeight = sh;
        }
        //Convert asset to bitmap
        public function bm(AssetsName:String):Object {
            var a:Object = new AssetsName(stageWidth, stageHeight);
            return new Bitmap(a);
        }

    }
}
```

And the main class that is referenced in Main.fla

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import library.AssetHandler;

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        private var cannon:Cannon = new Cannon();
        private var holder:Holder = new Holder();
            //I want to replace this
        public var bdata = new Char(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
        public var char = new Bitmap(bdata);
            //into this
            public var asset = new AssetHandler(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
            public var char = asset.bm("Char");

        private var cannonAngle:Number;

        public function Main() {
                }
        }
}
```

In php you can easily do $Class->$name();
Is there a similar approach in AS3?

I get the errors:
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method AssetsName.
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Bitmap.

I imagine that the Bitmap method is not found due to visibility, but how do i fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: In php you can easily do $Class->$name(); Is there a similar approach in AS3? - I'd think That's one of the things you can only do in php. That and variable variables ($$var).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Bitmap.
```

You'll need to import [`flash.display.Bitmap`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Bitmap.html&ei=AS2wTqCBLJHAtgfB762cAg&usg=AFQjCNEzyi1u7Be7Fj9T64hDQj5pM-4B7g).

```
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method AssetsName.
```

If I remember correctly, you can't actually instantiate a class from a String reference like you're doing. You can, however, do a [`getDefinitionByName`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html&ei=5y2wTsreBZGctwfPk4WMCQ&usg=AFQjCNFwwQ-mBydvnGYRZIhzP4Gm0pVcOw) using the string reference, and instantiate a class that way.

```
public function bm(AssetsName:String):Object {
    var classdef:Class = getDefinitionByName(AssetsName) as Class;
    var a:Object = new classdef(stageWidth, stageHeight);
    return new Bitmap(a);
}
```

(I think that's correct. There may be some errors.) (Edit: There was - missed the "as Class" part.)

Good luck.

Comment: Sweet! Just what I needed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this

If you need get reference of class by string:

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
.....
var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("YourClass") as Class;
```

If you want call function by string:

```
var functionName:String = "testFunction";
this[functionName]("hello!");

public function testFunction(param:String):void {
    trace(param);
}
```

Hope this help you.

**UPDATE**

```
PHP's $Class->$name() may be assumed as classInstance["name"](); in ActionScript
```

Comment: I've seen this approach in google search results however it doesn't suit me, because I cannot use "this" unless i create a method for each asset individually which I'm trying to avoid, because there will be a lot of them. Thanks for the import thingy, saved me some time on that!